# Payment shortcut link for Google Pay?

Tags: links, payments

Does Google Pay support a shortcut link to sending a payment to an email address?  I want to put a payment link on my website.

For example, Paypal supports a link format like `https://www.paypal.me/username/amount` that auto-configures their "Send Payment" screen to auto-fill the recipient and amount fields.

I can't find any explicit mention of this in Google Pay's docs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I closed this because it appears to be about using Google Pay and not about running your own website.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If questions about implementing payment links on your website has nothing to do with running your own website, can you suggest a better Stackexchange site for such questions?

Comment: If you need the link for your website, it is on-topic here.   I edited it to clarify and re-opened the question.

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#tutorial)